# django/mysql table not found - django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'trustline.authentication_user' doesn't exist")

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, backend, mysql-python

I was trying to `makemigrations` for my project but whenever I do this, I got this error:

> ```
> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'trustline.authentication_user' doesn't exist"
> ```

And I have this line in `settings.py`:

> ```
> AUTH_USER_MODEL = "authentication.User"
> ```

Here's the full traceback of the error:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please just copy-paste the exception as text, don't post it as an image, let alone _two_ images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your error stems from attempting to use the database at import time.
In Django, it's a big no-no to use the database on module level in a module that may be imported during your application's initialization time, since the application needs to be initialized so you can make or run migrations, and if such a database call requires a table that hasn't yet been migrated into existence... well, here we are.

Looking at the traceback, that happens in `utility/email_sending.py`, line 27, an invocation of `get_admin_emails()`.

For this particular problem, the fix should be to

- remove `ADMIN_EMAILS = get_admin_emails()` (and instead just call `get_admin_emails()` wherever you might be using `ADMIN_EMAILS` right now).
- and if you want the same performance you had before, slap an `@lru_cache` or `@cache` decorator on `get_admin_emails()` so it ever does its work once.

Comment: perfect! 
i commented these lines, but it also doesn't want to migrate
here's the error
https://imgur.com/a/sr5zeei

Comment: That's an entirely different error, you know? _That_ stems from your Python version being too old for the libraries you're using. `from __future__ import annotations` requires Python 3.7 or newer.

Comment: i updated to python 3.9 and i did
sudo mv /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python3.7
sudo ln -s $(which python3.9) /usr/bin/python

but when i'm check the version it still 3.6.9
what should i do?

Comment: I don't know why you've updated your Python like that, but it's because you're in a virtualenv. You need to recreate your virtualenv using the new Python version.

Comment: In addition, if you are using a table that's created on Django's first migrate call i.e Users_Authentication table, you have to block off all modules utilizing the object, make the first migration, then unblock the modules and make migrations again. Its the order that matters